# How to add ToolTips for each item in a Combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox, tooltip

I have searched for various solutions, but none have given me a direct answer or is not written in vb.net. But my situation is that I have a `ComboBox` with a few items that a user can select. I want to add simple tooltips so each user knows what he or she is selecting. However, the tooltip does not show until an item is selected. I want the tooltip to show when the mouse hovers over each item.

Below is my code:

```
Private Sub VotingAgentComboBox_MouseHover(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles VotingAgentComboBox.MouseHover
    Dim VotingAgentToolTip As New ToolTip
    If VotingAgentComboBox.Text = "ISS" Then VotingAgentToolTip.SetToolTip(VotingAgentComboBox, "You selected ISS")
End Sub
```

Comment: it is only doing the selected item because you are testing selected item: `If VotingAgentComboBox.Text`.  The individual items dont get mouse events, so a ToolTip will be difficult without subclassing or usinf WndProc.  OR use more descriptive text in the CBO.  You can store Objects in `Items`, not just strings, so you can write Class to store whatever is in the CBO and override `ToString` to provide longer, descriptive text for the Items list.

Comment: Thank you for that input, I understand my issue now, however how would I go about the sub class then?

Comment: [here is a sample](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e234c4a7-0cf7-4284-a072-8152f7593002/combobox-item-highlight-event?forum=winforms) which ends subclassing AND doing Owner Draw AND WndProc to get at the ItemHighlight event which you could use to show a tooltip.  Its an odd controls - sort of like a UserControl with several pieces.  **MUCH** easier to provide nicer descriptions to start with

Comment: These two links may help you! 1. [A-Windows-Forms-ComboBox-with-Item-ToolTips-for-32](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18803/A-Windows-Forms-ComboBox-with-Item-ToolTips-for-32)
2. [change-combobox-items-text-color-on-hover](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/269678-change-combobox-items-text-color-on-hover/)

Answer (score 1):

try this..
Add tooltip Control to to your Forms and write this code to DrawItem event to combobox control

And drawmode property of combobox set to OwnerDrawFixed

```
if (e.Index == -1) { return; }

            Point p = new Point(ComboBox1.Location.X + 120, ComboBox1.Location.Y + ComboBox1.Height + (30 + e.Index * 10));



            if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
            {

                toolTip.Show(ComboBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), this, p);

            }



            e.DrawBackground();

            e.Graphics.DrawString(ComboBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, Brushes.Black, new Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));
```

Answer (score 0):

Heena, the code you posted works flawlessly! thanks.

```
  private void CmbUnit_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        if (e.Index >= 0)
        {
            UnitItem item = Items[e.Index] as UnitItem;
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, item.unit_str, e.Font, e.Bounds,
                e.ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter);
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();

            Point p = new Point(Location.X + 120, Location.Y + Height + (30 + e.Index * 10));
            if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
            {
                ttip.Show(item.unit_name, this, 2000);
            }
        }
    }
```